# Audio android does forces closes app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-audiomanager, android-handler

I have created an audio player with a list view of songs, when the user clicks on an item of the list view the music player starts and a button to pause it, all this worked fine!

My next stop i implemented a seek bar to update progress of the song and two text views one for current duration of song and one for total duration of song. I have written the code and everything seems to be fine but every time i run it keeps force closing

Help please!

the .Java class

```
public class Nasheeds extends ListActivity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
//ArrayList holds the data (as HashMaps) to load into the ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
//SimpleAdapter does the work to load the data in to the ListView
private SimpleAdapter sa;
private MediaPlayer mp;
public boolean istrue = true;
 private ImageButton btnPrevious;
 private ImageButton btnNext;

 private SeekBar songProgressBar;
 private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
 private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;

 //Handler to update UI timer, progress bar
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
 private Utilities utils;
 private int seekForwardTime = 5000; //500 milliseconds
 private int seekBackwardTime = 5000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nasheeds2);



    //HashMap links each line of data to the correct TextView
    HashMap<String,String> item;
    for(int i=0;i<Nasheed.length;i++){
      item = new HashMap<String,String>();
      item.put( "line1", Nasheed[i][0]);
      item.put( "line2", Nasheed[i][1]);

      list.add( item );
    }

    sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.nasheeds1,
            new String[] { "line1","line2" },
            new int[] {R.id.displayname, R.id.title});

    setListAdapter(sa);



    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    btnNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    utils = new Utilities();

    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);






  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch (arg2)
        {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("User selected option 1");
        //  mp.stop();
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
               mp.stop();
           }else
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Nasheeds.this, R.raw.mok);
            mp.start();

            // MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Nasheeds.this, R.raw.mok);  
            //  mp.start(); 

            TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
            tv.setText("Playing "+ "Mountains of Mekkah, Zain Bikha");

            //set progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            //updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
       /*     catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IO Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("User selected option 2");
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
               mp.stop();
           }else
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Nasheeds.this, R.raw.hnim);
            mp.start();

        case 2:

            break;                  
        }

    }

  });



  View playbtn = findViewById(R.id.play);
playbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (istrue) {
              mp.pause();
              istrue = false;
          } else {
              mp.start();
              istrue = true;
          }



          }


});


btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       /* if(currentSongIndex > 0){
            playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
        }else{
            // play last song
            playSong(list.size() - 1);
            currentSongIndex = list.size() - 1;
        }*/
        System.out.println("Click Works");

    }
});


btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Click Works");
    }
});
}






public void updateProgressBar(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
  }

 private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
          long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
          long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

          //displaying total duration time
          songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
          //displaying time completed playing
          songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

          //updating progress bar
          int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
          songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

          //running this thread after 100 milliseconds
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
  };
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();
}

   private String[][] Nasheed =
        {{"Mountains of Mekkah","Zain Bikha"},
        {"His name is Mohammed","Kamal Uddin"},
        {"Hadith 3",".....add hadith"},};

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


}

}
```

The Utils Class

```
package com.example.fuelfinder;

public class Utilities {
 /**
 * Function to convert milliseconds time to
 * Timer Format
 * Hours:Minutes:Seconds
 * */
public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    // Convert total duration into time
       int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
       int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
       int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
       // Add hours if there
       if(hours > 0){
           finalTimerString = hours + ":";
       }

       // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
       if(seconds < 10){
           secondsString = "0" + seconds;
       }else{
           secondsString = "" + seconds;}

       finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}

/**
 * Function to get Progress percentage
 * @param currentDuration
 * @param totalDuration
 * */
public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
    Double percentage = (double) 0;

    long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
    long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

    // calculating percentage
    percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

    // return percentage
    return percentage.intValue();
}

/**
 * Function to change progress to timer
 * @param progress -
 * @param totalDuration
 * returns current duration in milliseconds
 * */
public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
    int currentDuration = 0;
    totalDuration = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
    currentDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);

    // return current duration in milliseconds
    return currentDuration * 1000;
}
}
```

xml file 1

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/displayname"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:textSize="15dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="15dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

second xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selectedfile"
            android:text="Not file selected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"/>

    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/prev"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
                    android:onClick="doClick"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
                    android:onClick="doClick"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

The LogCat:

```
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuelfinder/com.example.fuelfinder.Nasheeds}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.fuelfinder.Nasheeds.onCreate(Nasheeds.java:79)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: in your com.example.fuelfinder.Nasheeds.OnCreate (line 79), a null exception is being thrown. It's probably your SongProgressBar which isn't found !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since StackOverflow doesn't have line numbers, it's hard to tell specifically what's going on, but the offending line in the exception is rather clear:

> 12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-07 14:43:02.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.fuelfinder.Nasheeds.onCreate(Nasheeds.java:79)

I have a feeling that if you set a breakpoint there, you'll be able to find the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); I have not yet learned to debug using eclipse yet, after placing breakpoint on this line i click debug but i cant find where on eclipse it shows what is happening at this line

Comment: found what i was looking for and it was the line you mentioned quick fix was not doing anything onCompletion method so added inside to go to next track on completion